# Showing anchor href links formatted normally

Tags: browser, text-formatting, links

In reading user generated content on the web where links are allowed in the content,  I have encountered cases where the normal underline text format (that indicates that the text is a link) is overridden so that the text format is the same as the rest of the content.

Obviously viewing the source of the page would show any hidden links, but I wonder if any super users have figured out how to discover these things in a more expedient way.

The page might look like this:

```
 Plain text <a href="https://superusercom" target="_blank"><font color="Black">looks the same</font></a> continued plain...
```

Plain text looks the same continued plain...

Note that "looks the same", above, is a link to superuser.com, but this site does not allow it to be a link (you can see it if you hit edit on this post).

Comment: You can override the link colour - in Firefox at least

Comment: @DavidPostill, I tried it in Firefox (Settings > General > Colors > Manage Colors) and it does work. It also messes up the background color, on all unvisited links, but that's a Firefox problem.